# is there anything like magento module fallback

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cart, extensions, theme-fallback

we created own theme by extending rwd theme and cart page was using below file code :

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/theme1/template/checkout/cart/default.phtml
```

we created **custom module** and it includes some features in Listing, view & cart page :

after installing module, cart page is displaying using below code.

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/module/cart/item/default.phtml` = > cart page.

we **dont need features present in cart page**, so we renamed the default.phtml file

but than i thought it will use **fallback** and cart page will display using below path

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/theme1/template/checkout/cart/default.phtml
```

but now in cart page, "name, sku, price" and no other information are displaying.

layout file of module :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>preorder/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template>preorder/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>preorder/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>preorder/css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>preorder/product/all-view.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="addtocart14" template="preorder/product/view/addtocart14.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="addtocart17" template="preorder/product/view/addtocart17.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>preorder/product/all-list.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list14" template="preorder/product/list/list14.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list15" template="preorder/product/list/list15.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list16" template="preorder/product/list/list16.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list17" template="preorder/product/list/list17.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>preorder/product/all-list.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list14" template="preorder/product/list/list14.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list15" template="preorder/product/list/list15.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list16" template="preorder/product/list/list16.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list17" template="preorder/product/list/list17.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>preorder/product/all-list.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list14" template="preorder/product/list/list14.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list15" template="preorder/product/list/list15.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list16" template="preorder/product/list/list16.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list17" template="preorder/product/list/list17.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>preorder/product/all-list.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list14" template="preorder/product/list/list14.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list15" template="preorder/product/list/list15.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list16" template="preorder/product/list/list16.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list17" template="preorder/product/list/list17.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>
    <tag_product_list>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>preorder/product/all-list.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list14" template="preorder/product/list/list14.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list15" template="preorder/product/list/list15.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list16" template="preorder/product/list/list16.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list17" template="preorder/product/list/list17.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </tag_product_list>


</layout>
```

Comment: are u rename `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/module/cart/item/default.phtml`?

Comment: @AmitBera you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you have to place the default magento default.phtml file 
at **app/design/frontend/rwd/theme1/template/module/cart/item/default.phtml**

as your module is active and you have define in your module to get this file from **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/module/cart/item/default.phtml**  directory if you don't want to load this file then either remove this from configuration or place a default one in your modules directory as mentioned above.

You might have defined in your modules layout file to use **app/design/frontend/rwd/theme1/template/module/cart/item/default.phtml**  either change your layout file or place the default magento file in your theme for the same location.

hope this will help you.

Comment: let me check , i will let you know soon

Comment: i updated layouts module file, please check in question. and tell me what i need to change to fix this issue , i dont want to copy the code of the `theme1/default.phtml` to `module/default.phtml`

Comment: you need to update code <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>preorder/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template>preorder/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>preorder/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

Comment: if you remove this code you will be able to load default magento file. either remove this or update new path.

Answer (score 1):

**As per as question your custom module have changes--**

*Cart item's phtml file*

from  `checkout/cart/default.phtml`

to `module/checkout/cart/default.phtml`

At default, *Cart items in cart page* are render from  **different block classe** but call `same phtml for render view`.

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
................
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
                <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

.........
```

You have see that if

- *a Cart item product type* is `simple` then it view render from `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer`.

*a Cart item product type* is `grouped` then it view render from `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Grouped`.

etc.

**May those block classes are rewrited by your module or change by your module layout file.** which changed your cart item phtml file location as you mentioned

For your solution copy :

`app/design/frontend/rwd/theme1/template/checkout/cart/default.phtml`  to

```
app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/module/checkout/cart/default.phtml
```

Comment: means are you telling i have to copy the default.phtml from theme and i have to paste in `module/checkout/cart.phtml` ?

Comment: i updated layouts module file, please check in question. and tell me what i need to change to fix this issue , i dont want to copy the code of the `theme1/default.phtml` to `module/default.phtml`

Comment: It's really nice & usefull information. I follwed your solution. It worked fine. But as other user gave the answer first, i accept his answer.